# How to re-grid a shapefile onto a different hex grid in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, grids-graticules, hexagonal-grid

I have a source shapefile on a hex grid (output from ArcGIS Pro Optimized Hot Spot Analysis tool) and a target shapefile on a hex grid (generated using Generate Tessellation tool). Both use EPSG 8857 as their CRS but their geometries are different. I want to re-grid/alter my source shapefile to be on the hex grid of my target shapefile.

Comment: What do you mean by "geometries are different.", if they are both hex grids? Add an image to your question to explain why its not working.